# merge JSON objects without new keys

Tags: javascript, json

How to merge two JSON objects but do not include properties that don't exist in the first Object?

### Input

```
var obj1 = { x:'', y:{ a:'', b:'' } };
var obj2 = { x:1, y:{ a:1, b:2, c:3 }, z:'' };
```

### Output

```
obj1 = { x:1, y:{ a:1, b:2 } };
```

ps. There is a method for Objects called [preventExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) but it appears to only block the immediate extension of properties and not deeper ones.

Comment: Phrase the question in the question, post the answer as an answer, and accept it.

Comment: @vsync: It's a great idea to post solutions to help other people in the future, but you should format it as follows; 1) Post a question "pretending" to ask the question, 2) post your solution as an answer to your own question, and accept your own answer as the solution. Who knows, you might even get another answer giving a different (better?) approach!

Comment: good idea, I will do as you advised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/*
    Recursively merge properties of two objects 
    ONLY for properties that exist in obj1
*/

var obj1 = { x:'', y:{ a:'', b:'' } };
var obj2 = { x:1, y:{ a:1, b:2, c:3 }, z:'' };

function merge(obj1, obj2) {
    for( var p in obj2 )
        if( obj1.hasOwnProperty(p) )
            obj1[p] = typeof obj2[p] === 'object' ? merge(obj1[p], obj2[p]) : obj2[p];

    return obj1;
}

merge(obj1, obj2 );
console.dir( obj1 ); // { x:1, y:{ a:1, b:2 } }
```

Comment: please REFACTOR this to the max

Comment: You should use `continue` instead of `break` to skip a property; currently it stops the complete loop if it encounters a non-existing property.

Comment: I have refactored my code since, to use 'prop IN obj' testing

Comment: I'm wondering why you don't use `obj1.hasOwnProperty(p)` as well. It's only about properties that `obj1` has itself without the prototype ones.

Comment: => I wonder if I could just settle with `if( p in obj1 )` instead of the `hasOwnProperty`

Answer (score 0):

Minor tweak to the solution, adding support for arrays (replace, not append - that would be harder):

```
function merge(obj1, obj2) {
    for( var p in obj2 )
        if( obj1.hasOwnProperty(p) )
            obj1[p] = (typeof obj2[p] === 'object' && !(p.length)) ? merge(obj1[p], obj2[p]) : obj2[p];

    return obj1;
}
```