# Merge existing elements with jQuery.extend

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

[`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) helps to merge object in the way like:

```
var a = {
    'x': 2,
    'y': 3,
    'etc': {
        'm': 3,
        'n': 5
    }
};
var b = {
    'x': 4,
    'z': 1,
    'etc': {
        'm': 2,
        'p': 3
    }
};

$.extend(true, a, b); // true for recursively merge
/* Result:
    a = {
        'x': 4,
        'y': 3,
        'z': 1,
        'etc': {
            'm': 2,
            'n': 5,
            'p': 5
        }
    };
*/
```

But what I am interested in is only the properties that already exist in `a`, which means, for example, if `z` is not a property of `a`, it shouldn't be in the result. So the expected result should be:

```
a = {
    'x': 4,
    'y': 3,
    'etc': {
         'm': 2,
         'n': 5,
     }
};
```

I wonder if there is an easy way to achieve this with jQuery, or can only achieved using brute force like this one (under the condition that `a` has at most 2 layers):

```
for (var i in b) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        if (typeof a[i] === 'object') {
            for (var j in b[i]) {
                if (a[i].hasOwnProperty(j)) {
                    a[i][j] = b[i][j];
                }
            }
        } else {
            a[i] = b[i];
        }
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hUkAS/3/

Comment: So you are kinda asking for a `left-merge`!

Comment: this seems to be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997342/merge-json-objects-without-new-keys

Answer (score 0):

I m not aware of such a function, but I wrote a generic function which will merge two objects(hash) width any number of layers.

```
//The function
function leftMerge(a, b) {
    for (var i in b) {
        if (a.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            console.log(typeof a[i]);
            if (typeof a[i] == 'object' && typeof b[i]== 'object')
                leftMerge(a[i], b[i]);
            else
                a[i] = b[i]
        }
    }
}

// a test
var obj_a = {
    'x': 2,
    'y': 3,
    'etc': {
        'm': 3,
        'n': 5,
        'j': {
            'h': 15,
            'i':16
        }
    }
};
var obj_b = {
    'x': 4,
    'z': 1,
    'etc': {
        'm': 2,
        'p': 3,
        'j': {
            'i':2,
            'l':22
        }
    }
};

leftMerge(obj_a, obj_b);
console.log(obj_a);
```

I hope that helps.